# How to group rows in dataframe based on common values (strings) present in multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this table in Pandas
[image: Raw Data]

I am supposed to group the data according to ‘Sub_category’ so that there is only 1 entry for each ‘Sub_category’.

All the item names in a ‘Sub_category’ should appear only in one of the three Category
columns. If an Item name appears in more than one Category columns, the priority of Item shall be: Category 2 > Category 3 > Category 1.

The final output file (I grouped these manually) should look like this:

Output Expected:
[image: Output Expected]

Comment: can you share the data in a code block instead of picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
uniq_subcat = df['Sub_category'].unique()
scat_cat1=[]; scat_cat2=[]

for scat in uniq_subcat:
    scat_cat1.append(','.join(set(df[df['Sub_category']==scat]['Category1'])))
    scat_cat2.append(','.join(set(df[df['Sub_category']==scat]['Category2'])))

df_result['Sub_category'] = uniq_subcat
df_result['Category1'] = scat_cat1
df_result['Category2'] = scat_cat2
```

Here df is the input dataset and df_result is what you wanted.